# Android convert gmt time to readable date

Tags: java, android, datetime, gmt

In android I would like to convert "2015-11-10T17:00:00-0500" to a readable date format such as :

Nov 31, 2015
Nov 31, 2015 4:00:00 PM
4:00:00 PM  12:00:00 AM

what would be the best way to do this, I have tried and failed using the Date method

Comment: Show us what you have tried and failed with then. (Note `DateFormat` should be involved somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SimpleDateFormat, something like this:

```
String time = "2015-11-10T17:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"); 
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);

    String out = dateFormat2.format(date);
    Log.e("Time", out);
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting type, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Your date-time string has a timezone offset of `-0500` i.e. the corresponding date-time in UTC is `2015-11-10T22:00:00Z` where `Z` stands for Zulu and is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset i.e. `Etc/UTC` timezone which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours.

The type which represents date-time along with the timezone offset is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). In order to format it into different patterns, you need a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d'T'H:m:sXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-11-10T17:00:00-0500", dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd, uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd, uuuu h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput3 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        String output1 = dtfOutput1.format(odt);
        String output2 = dtfOutput2.format(odt);
        String output3 = dtfOutput3.format(odt);

        System.out.println(output1);
        System.out.println(output2);
        System.out.println(output3);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Tue 10, 2015
Tue 10, 2015 5:00:00 PM
5:00:00 PM
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>